# PSQL returns wrong results

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I'm running the following query in our database, I get the incorrect result:

```
db_name=# select * from user_session where user_id = 30950 and study_id = 1249;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+-------------------------------------
user_id          | 30950
activity_id      | 6219
study_id         | 1163
...
```

As you can see, I query for study_id 1249, but PSQL returns study_id 1163! To the best of my knowledge this single record is the only one with this issue. We found it through the bug it caused in our code.

It's a very odd situation. I also can query by `activity_id`, and get the wrong record as well:

```
db_name=# select * from user_session where user_id = 30950 and activity_id = 6478;
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+-------------------------------------
user_id          | 30950
activity_id      | 6219
study_id         | 1163
...
```

As you can see, I query for activity_id 6478, while I get the activity_id 1163.

A bit more context:

- Both activity_id and study_id are FK to other tables.
- We are running Postgres 11.5 using docker on two servers, one as master, the other as slave. This query was executed on master.
- A couple of days ago there was an issue that we had to reindex one of the large tables, but not related to this table!

Any idea why this is happening?

#### Edit 1:

The following are the field types, and the indices on this table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.user_session (
    activity_id integer NOT NULL,
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    study_id integer NOT NULL,
    ...
);

CREATE INDEX db_name_view_userschedules_00b3bd7e ON public.user_session USING btree (activity_id);
CREATE INDEX db_name_view_userschedules_e8701ad4 ON public.user_session USING btree (user_id);
CREATE INDEX db_name_view_usersession_study_id_12700d52 ON public.user_session USING btree (study_id);
```

Comment: What datatype are those columns? Does reindexing that table fix this? Can you please **[edit]** your question and add the complete `create index` statements for all indexes on that table?

Comment: It's a large table in our production environment, so I've been hesitant to reindex it. Was trying to see if I can find a way to understand what's going on!

Comment: Possibly a corrupt index. See https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/how-to-fix-postgresql-index-corruption-deal-repair-rebuild for suggestions on finding and solving the issue.